# Linux Kernel Device Driver Write Callback is writing data across the entire allocated memory space for the device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, xilinx

I have a Xilinx SoC, and have created a simple multiplier on the programmable logic via verilog. The multiplier takes two 16 bit input, multiplies them and returns a 32 bit output. The digital design have been packaged and linked to the processor system that is within the SoC via an AXI-Lite interface. The Xilinx tools have auto-generated a device tree entity for this digital design so that a custom linux device driver can be created to interact with the digital design (i.e the PS will treat it just like an external hardware device connected to the ARM processor).

The device tree generated looks like this:

```
/ {
    amba_pl: amba_pl@0 {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        ranges ;
        multi2_0: multi2@a0000000 {
            clock-names = "s00_axi_aclk";
            clocks = <&zynqmp_clk 71>;
            compatible = "xlnx,multi2-1.0";
            reg = <0x0 0xa0000000 0x0 0x10000>;
            xlnx,s00-axi-addr-width = <0x4>;
            xlnx,s00-axi-data-width = <0x20>;
        };
    };
};
```

So from the device tree we can see that the multiplier ("multi2-1.0") has a physical memory address of 0xa0000000, with address width of 0x4 and data width of 32 bits.

So, from the device driver point of view, specifically in the write call-back function, I am writing a 32-bit number into the virtual memory address that was retrieved from "ioremap(.)" function.

A sanity check was done to see the virtual memory mapping to physical address, and it seems to be correctly done with no errors (some memory-related code snippets from the driver is shown below):

```
struct simpmod_local {
    int irq;
    unsigned long mem_start;
    unsigned long mem_end;
    void __iomem *base_addr;
};
struct simpmod_local *lp = NULL;
```

......

```
static int simpmod_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{ .....
lp->base_addr = ioremap(lp->mem_start, lp->mem_end - lp->mem_start + 1);
...
dev_info(dev,"simpmod at 0x%08x mapped to 0x%08x, irq=%d\n",
        (unsigned int __force)lp->mem_start,
        (unsigned int __force)lp->base_addr,
        lp->irq); 
....
}
```

The write call-back function (as of now), is just taking a 32-bit number and placing it into memory. However, the read call-back function is just reading that exact same number even though I am reading from a base_address+0x20_offset. I have tried changing the offset value, but regardless, it keeps reading that same number.

My intuition tell me, that if reading from a different memory address the value should be either garbage value or zero, but its very unlikely to be reading the same value written to the base address. Any ideas to why the written data is copied across the entire allocated memory space?

Even doing a devmem command <devmem 0xa0000000 w 52> will produce the output 52 when executing <devmem 0xa0000020 w>  or <devmem 0xa0000040 w> or ......

The write-callback function looks like this:

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *fil, const char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off){
  sscanf (buf,"%d,%d",&operand_1,&operand_2);
  ker_buf[len] = 0 ;
  iowrite32((unsigned int) operand_1, lp->base_addr);
  return len;
}
```

The full project code (with minor changes) can be found on https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/Memory-Replications-during-write-call-back-function-in-Linux/m-p/1212405

Comment: So the read callback is where you actually observe a surprising result?  Have you not considered that the error might be there?

Comment: Why are you using `sscanf` [inside a _driver_] to get a port address? `sscanf` is _slow_ and is never used in a driver in the way you're using it. What is `operand_2` [which you're _not_ using for anything]? Add a `printk` to show all the relevant values [before writing]. Many drivers that need userspace to write to a port would probably _not_ map this to the device `write` callback, but would create a [custom] `ioctl` with a `struct` you devise. Having a global `lp` is bad juju. `lp` should come from the per-device private pointer in `platform_device`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hello John, the read call back (as of now) is just basically a ioread32((unsigned int __force)lp->base_addr+0x20); I have been testing it for a while so it is kind of messy right now. But basically, my issue is that regardless of what the offset is (currently 0x20) the read value is the same. Similar issue happens when running devmem from the command line.

Comment: Hello @CraigEstey, thanks for the pointers. Do you think thats where the issue is (keep in mind that devmem causes the same weird issue).

Comment: I'd try to find a Xilinx supplied device driver for a standard device that they provide to use as a reference design for the DTB/DTC entry and how to use it. The code that scans the DTB and extracts the data is missing [here]. I'd add some diagnostic code [called from `probe` or `open`] that verifies simple operation: `2*2 == 4`, `17 * 37 == 629`, etc. with hardwired calls [vs. waiting for data from userspace]. You could even have it dump the surrounding memory words looking for the [known] result. Is the multiplier a standard macro [provided by Xilinx] or a custom design of your own?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @CraigEstey. I have tried to look for one but most of them are really advanced (..and I am just a beginner in this area). I found a tutorial that is exactly the same (but was done 5 years ago), and I followed it and mine faced this memory bug unlike his. I tried fixing the values instead of taking it from user space but same issue was seen. "You could even have it dump the surrounding memory words looking for the [known] result" <-- do you do that from the command line or from the driver it self (not sure how to do that). The multiplier is a custom design.

Comment: Perhaps it's your expectations that are wrong.  If you're reading from memory that is mapped to a device -- or maybe to nothing at all if it's in a range reserved for devices but not mapped -- then I'm not sure it's reasonable to assume that you will observe different behavior than you do.

Comment: That is possible that my expectations are wrong. I will try changing the lp from being global and the other pointers that @CraigEstey suggested as well. The thing is, I have seen write issues in which it results in segmentation errors, bad value written, writing to a wrong memory address, corrupted data, etc. I have never seen writing a value, and reading it correctly but having that data replicated throughout memory. That is the weird part

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* This isn't so much a solution as some observations and things to try [in no particular order].

At present, you've got multiple potential sources of error: bad H/W logic, incorrect device driver.

From the linked driver code, most `return` statements return an error code (e.g. `-ENOMEM`) but some do `return -1`. This is inconsistent.

As I mentioned in my comments, you've got a bunch of globals. There is no interthread locking. So, you could have race conditions.

I presume you're booting `petalinux`. And, it is working as long as you don't access *your* device. This is a *big* deal [in a good way].

I'm assuming that you're communicating with it via a serial cable from your development system [running (e.g.) `minicom`] to an onboard UART. So, you get a login prompt and/or shell.

This means that the UART driver source [and the corresponding dtb/dts] is available. You can use that as your reference driver. Or, something else like GPIO, etc.

I notice that you mentioned `ZYNQ` [which is a fairly popular Xilinx FPGA chip]. I'll assume that you're also using a standard SDK board with a `ZYNQ` chip on it. So, Vivado will already know about the board interconnect/layout.

And, I assume that Vivado is able to pass off the board definition to Xilinx's S/W SDK/builder, so that it can build a compatible `petalinux` kernel.

> I have never seen writing a value, and reading it correctly but having that data replicated throughout memory.

This means that the address matching logic in your device is responding not merely to its assigned address range, but many more addresses that it shouldn't. There could be overlap with *other* devices and they could be contending/racing.

I'm *no* Vivado expert, but ...

From your link, looking at the `.png` for one of the Vivado windows, it says that the `AXI BASEADDR` is `0xFFFFFFFF` and that `AXI HIGHADDR` is `0x00000000`. Both have a blue `i` on them.

These are highly suspicious to me because I think these values should match with the values in the DTB entry. And, the `BASEADDR` value makes no sense to me.

I'm wondering if the DTB could be generated to some sane address but the actual H/W logic generated is different.

This could easily cause all the symptoms you're seeing.

One thing that might help is to add `chipscope` to the H/W design so you can debug your H/W logic and/or observe any access to a given port/address range.

You're using `copy_to_user` et. al. But, this can fail and you're not checking the error code. I'd also do a `printk` on the arguments being passed.

There is no guarantee that the `len` value passed to `dev_read/dev_write` is sufficient to contain the transfer size. In `dev_read`, you do `ioread32`. But, then you do: `int n = sprintf(ker_buf, "%d\n", read_val);` You're *not* checking `n` vs `len` to ensure there's enough room. And, you're *not* examining/honoring `loff_t`

Both these functions are passed a `struct file` pointer. But, this value is ignored in favor of the global variables you've already set. As, I mentioned in my top comments, using these globals is problematic. You should use the passed pointer to find the appropriate `struct` pointers and [ultimately] your private device struct `simpmod_local`.

Your `dev_write` should store the values from userspace into the private struct. The `dev_read` should get them from there.

Here's a total *guess*: Most designs I've seen use full `AXI` rather than `AXI` lite. I know nothing about what constitutes an "AXI thread ID", so I don't know what the implications of your access code bouncing between cores might be [if anything].

Using `dev_write/dev_read` as you're doing isn't atomic. I think, at present, you've got more fundamental issues. But, long term, I'd replace this with an `ioctl` call that takes a `struct`, such as:

```
struct mymult_user {
    u32 operand_1;
    u32 operand_2;
    u32 result;
};
```

The `ioctl` call does `copy_from_user` on this. Sends these values to the H/W, gets back the result. And, returns the result to the ioctl caller. Or, it can do a `copy_to_user` on the `result` field in the `struct`.

Overall, you're more likely to get a [useful] response on Xilinx's forum page [as it's frequented by people who do this stuff all the time].

---

**UPDATE:**

Something else I noticed.

The DTB entry specifies the AXI data width to be 0x20. This is 32 *bytes*!? It's autogenerated so it *must* be correct ;-) But, this seems excessive to me. It may just be related to the width of the AXI data bus, so, maybe not an issue ...

But, looking at the driver, the offsets from the base address don't seem to match up.

`operand_1` is offset 0x10, `operand_2` is offset 0x20, and the result is offset 0x30. So, what's at offset 0x0???

The width of the AXI bus and the width of the registers may *not* be strictly related.

One way to view this is that the offsets should be aligned to the bus width: 0x0, 0x20, 0x40.

But, ordinarily, I'd expect things to be more closely packed. (e.g.) offsets 0x0, 0x2, 0x4 respectively.

It might be less painful [less chance of memory/bus corruption] to *just* do `ioread*` while debugging. Since you're not *writing* to the address space, it's less likely to corrupt other memory cells and the system may stay alive [uncorrupted] longer. This would only give you whatever value was in result reg initially.

Also, you could write the operands and loop on `ioread32` for offsets (e.g.) 0x0-0x40 and `printk` those values.

Comment: Thank You Craig for your assistance. I will go through these comments right now and apply them to the project! Much appreciated .